# Word wrap in PISA PDF

Tags: django

I have a Django view that renders a piece of text and word wraps it. I am using the below CSS. When I convert the same to PDF using PISA, I dont see the word wrap and text is lost.

Do I need to set any properties on PISA for this?

```
{
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande","DejaVu Sans","Bitstream Vera Sans",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    word-wrap: break-word;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Pisa does not use CSS itself, it just implemented some of the CSS syntax and properties to apply its own rules in PDF generation.

See the section 6, [Cascading Style Sheets](https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/tree/master/doc), of the manual for the supported properties. And take a look at this [nice manual](http://pisa.spirito.de/data/pisa_api_en.pdf), that is a little bit more detailed.

It's hard to find good documentation about pisa.